# How to get files from Mac OS X desktop to Remote Server?

Tags: windows, macos, ssh, terminal.app

I typically use an FTP client to get files up to a server. But this time I was given remote access. So I am using Windows Remote Desktop Connection (on a Mac) and I am logged into the server. I see the window (looks just like a Windows computer inside of a Mac application) and navigated to the correct folder on the server where the files need to go. I have the files on my desktop and literally want to drag them to the window of the server, but that doesn't work.

I assume it's more advanced and I have to use the Mac App "Terminal" to get the files up but I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, don't use RDC use [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/). IMHO it's far superior to Microsoft's effort.

Using CoRD, setup a new connection checking 'Forward disks' in the process. Once you connect to the server open up 'My Computer' and you'll see your local drives mounted remotely as network shares.

You can then drag and drop to your hearts content :)

Comment: Thanks! This was a perfect solution for someone like me who has never really done this sort of thing before. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Its not mounting for me in Mac OSX Lion :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have Opera installed, you can use its built in file sharing (Opera unite). Public or password protected file sharing in two clicks. Then just download the files in a browser on the remote server. Quick and easy way to transfer a few files at least.